# Solving general non-homogenous wave equation with homogenous boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, wave-equation

I have been given the following PDE to solve:
$$
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=g(t)\sin x \;\;\; (t,x)\in (0,\infty)\times(0,\pi)\\u(0,x)=u_t(0,x) \;\;\;x\in(0,\pi)\\
u(t,0) = u(t,\pi) =0 \;\;\; t>0
$$

This shouldn't be too hard. I have to solve it by separating variables so I write $u(t,x)=v(t)w(x)$ and substituting this into the pde it's clear that $w(x)=\sin x$ and then I have the following ODE for $v$:
$$
v'' +v = g(t) \;\;\;\;\;: \;\;\;v(0)=v'(0)=0
$$

But I don't know how to solve this for a general $g(t)$. The solution they have given us says that:
$$
v(t) = \int_{0}^{t}g(t-\tau)\sin \tau \;\;d\tau
$$
I know this is something to do with Fourier series but I'm not sure why this applies in this case?

Any help welcome :)

Comment: Are you familiar with [Green's functions?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I have solved it but its not simple:

By looking at the ode we guess a solution of the form:

$$
v(t) = A(t)\cos(t)+B(t)\sin(t)$$
and then we differentiate twice. However, because we picked such a general form, we have a degree of freedom still to play with so we set:
$$
A'\cos t +B'\sin t = 0
$$
With this equation and with the ODE we derive the following system of simultaneous equations:
$$
B' \cos t - A' \sin t =g\\
A' \cos t + B\ \sin t =0
$$

We rearrange and solve for $A', B'$ and then integrate to get:

$$
A(t) = -\int_{0}^{t} g(s)\sin(s) \;ds\\
B(t) = \int_{0}^{t}g(s)\cos(s) \;\;ds
$$

Now we substitute this into our formula for $v$ and apply the compound angle formula for $\sin$ and then change variables $\tau = t-s$ and this gives us the solution:

$$
v(t) = \int_{0}^{t}g(t-\tau)\sin(\tau) \;\;d\tau
$$